# subl command line not working

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion, sublime-text-2

I followed the sublime text 2 command line tool installation feature some time ago and it was working just fine. However, it's not working anymore.

When I type subl in the command line, it returns nothing at all. When I cd into a dir and subl ., nothing is returned either.

I tried removing the subl file in my bin and reinstalling but it's still not working.

I'm running on OSX btw. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: When you say "nothing at all", what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error message or simply nothing? Did you change something in between? Where have you put it exactly (there are quite some `bin` directories all over the place in OS X)? What's the output of `ls -la $(which subl)`? Does it work if you run `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`?

Comment: dont you have to use it like: `subl somefile/subl .`     ?

Comment: @sannySin No, you use it like `subl <directories>` or `subl <files>`.

Comment: @slhck thanks for the response. When I enter the command, it won't return an error. It will go to the next line but sublime text won't startup. I've tried with sublime open and closed.

Comment: Okay, interesting. Could you also please answer all of the questions I've posted, ideally by [edit]ing your question and adding more info? Especially, what about running `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` standalone? Have you rebooted your system in between, or have you tried it on another user account, maybe? Or uninstalling Sublime?

Comment: same issue with the latest Sublime Text 3. Tried the obvious: 1) re-created the sym-link, still no joy. 2) called `subl` from the original location, also no joy.

`$ /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl .`
and then you just see the cursor -- no window pops up